# How to display posttypes and taxonomy in standard posts, not in a separate label?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, custom-field, taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I want to display some taxonomies directly in "Posts" label, as standard post, not in a separate label like "Books" for exp., but i don't know how.
Is there a way to do this?
This is the code:

class PostTypes {

```
var $types = array();
var $taxonomy = array();

function __construct($types = array(), $taxonomy = array()){
    $this->types = $types + $this->types;
    $this->taxonomy = $taxonomy + $this->taxonomy;
    $this->init();
}

function init(){
    add_action( 'init', array(&$this, 'register_post_type',) );
    add_action( 'init', array(&$this, 'register_taxonomy',) );
}


function register_post_type(){
    global $options;

    foreach ($this->types as $k => $v){
        $vowels = array('a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u');
        $a = 'a';
        $slug = $v['slug'];
        $name = $v['name'];

        $plural = $name.'s';
        $menu_name = $plural;
        if(isset($v['menu-name']))
            $menu_name = $v['menu-name'];

        $labels = array(
            'name'                  => __( $plural, 'post type general name' ),  
            'singular_name'         => __( $name, 'post type singular name' ),  
            'add_new'               => __( 'Add New', strtolower( $name ) ),  
            'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add New ' . $name ),  
            'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit ' . $name ),  
            'new_item'              => __( 'New ' . $name ),  
            'all_items'             => __( 'All ' . $plural ),  
            'view_item'             => __( 'View ' . $name ),  
            'search_items'          => __( 'Search ' . $plural ),  
            'not_found'             => __( 'No ' . strtolower( $plural ) . ' found'),  
            'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'No ' . strtolower( $plural ) . ' found in Trash'),  
            'parent_item_colon'     => '',  
            'menu_name'             => $menu_name

        );


        $supports = array('title','editor','thumbnail', 'comments');

        if(isset($v['supports'])){
            $supports = $v['supports'];
        }

        $args = array(
            'labels' => $labels,
            'public' => true,
            'publicly_queryable' => true,
            'show_ui' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => true,
            'query_var' => false,
            'rewrite' => array('slug' => $slug),
            'capability_type' => 'post',
            'has_archive' => false,
            'hierarchical' => false,
            'menu_position' => 5,
            'taxonomies' => array(),
            'supports' => $supports
        );
        register_post_type($k, $args);


    }
}


function register_taxonomy(){

    foreach ($this->taxonomy as $k => $v){

        $taxonomy_slug =  $v['slug'];

        $name = $v['name'];
        $plural = $name.'s';
        $types = $v['post-types'];


        $labels = array(
            'name' => __( $name, 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name' => __( $name, 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items'          => __( 'Search ' . $name ), 
            'popular_items' => __( 'Popular '.$name ),
            'all_items' => __( 'All '.$name ),
            'parent_item' => null,
            'parent_item_colon' => null,
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit '.$name ), 
            'update_item' => __( 'Update '.$name ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New '.$name ),
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New '.$name.' Name' ),
            'separate_items_with_commas' => __( 'Separate '.$name.' with commas' ),
            'add_or_remove_items' => __( 'Add or remove '.$name ),
            'choose_from_most_used' => __( 'Choose from the most used '.$name ),
            'menu_name' => __( $name ),
        );  

        if($v['type'] == 'category'){

            register_taxonomy($k, $types, array(
                'hierarchical' => true,
                'labels' => $labels,
                'show_ui' => true,
                'query_var' => true,
                'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => $taxonomy_slug, 'with_front' => false),
            ));

        }elseif($v['type'] == 'tags'){
            register_taxonomy($k, $types, array(
                'hierarchical' => false,
                'labels' => $labels,
                'show_ui' => true,
                'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
                'query_var' => true,
                'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => $taxonomy_slug, 'with_front' => false),
            ));


        }   

    }


}
```

}

Comment: same question as in my other comment- what are trying to get to appear under the Posts menu? your second code block creates a books post type and adds the default category taxonomy to books. you're not doing anything with posts here.

Comment: Yes, Milo, under the Posts menu.

Comment: WHAT under the posts menu???

Comment: What I'm trying to do, is to display this post type and taxonomy (BOOKS) - which is already registered - directly in standard post ( under the Posts menu ), not in a separately label, and to be compatible with standard WP posts.

Answer (score 1):

when you [register a taxonomy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy), the second argument is the post type it is available for:

```
register_taxonomy( $taxonomy, $object_type, $args );
```

if you want the taxonomy to work for a custom type as well as standard posts, you can pass an array of types:

```
$object_type = array( 'your_custom_type', 'post' );
```

alternately, you can use [`register_taxonomy_for_object_type`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy_for_object_type):

```
register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'your_custom_taxonomy', 'post' );
```

Comment: Milo, can you be more specific, please? I can't figure out how to apply what you say in this code.

Comment: Can somebody tell me, please, how to make it work? I struggle for a few days to find a solution, but nothing.

What must be change it or add it this code to work?

Comment: I suggest using `register_taxonomy_for_object_type` in your theme on the [`init`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init) action. modifying the code you posted is not a simple addition.